# Javascript Prompt that counts how many characters I have written and how many I have left

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undefined, nan

The code:

```js
var tweet = prompt("Write something here:");
alert("You have written " + tweet.lenght + " characters, you have " + (140 - tweet.lenght) + " characters left.");
```

The course that I am currently doing has a Javascript mini challenge and after I type in this prompt the data that I have, I get the following result:

You have written undefined characters, you have NaN characters left.

How to I get a normal output like : You have written 50 characters, you have 90 characters left.?

I have to mention that I am using a snippet in Chrome. And the course is from 2018. So it's been a while.

Comment: There is no property called `lenght`.  It's called `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a typo.
Change `lenght` to `length`